# Maven - How to compile tests without running them ? 

Tags: maven

Is there a way in Maven to compile the tests without running them ? I want to use the IDE to run specific tests and not all of them.

Comment: You should probably either edit the question or change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you can try to use parameter `-DskipTests`

References:

- [Maven Surefire Plugin # skipTests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skipTests)

Comment: In netbeans, that is what i was doing. I see the following mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dnetbeans.execution=true clean install then i see the following

Comment: [compiler:testCompile]
Not compiling test sources
[surefire:test]
Tests are skipped. Atleast using netbeans looks like if tests are skipped it does not compile test sources

Comment: never mind, even though the logs say that, it still seems to compile test files.

Comment: this leads to skipping tests completely: execution as well as compilation, see the correct answer below: test-compile. I use it with mvn clean compile test-compile in Eclipse

Comment: @Yashima you're right this aswer is not so clever...

please accept answer bellow, so a can delete this one

Comment: @Yashima You are talking about the `skip` option, aren't you? See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28740251/363573).

Comment: @lweller As far as I know this is the best solution for the question! Until now I used 'maven.test.skip=true' which produces missing test dependencies in cases where tests are not necessary.

Comment: for some reason, tests still run if -DskipTests is set.

Comment: you were supposed to delete the answer ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: According with the documentation `-DskipTests` compiles the test classes but does not execute them (or the test classes are skipped for execution) - to avoid compilation and execution should be used: `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`

Answer (score 431):

How about the `test-compile` lifecycle phase? It doesn't require any test skipping, because it occurs before the `test` phase. I.e.,

```
$ mvn test-compile
```

And done.

[Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) explains further.

Comment: Just curious, what is the advantage of `test-compile` over `-DskipTests`? - according with the documentation `-DskipTests` compiles the test classes but does **not** execute them (or the test classes are skipped for execution) - so according with `It doesn't require any test skipping` - should I assume that is expensive?

Comment: `-DskipTests` is not a Maven lifecycle goal; it's just an option to set. You could run lots of goals with `-DskipTests`. The OP asked how to compile them without running them, so this satisfies that. I don't see any reason to think skipping tests would be expensive, but it does seem useless to run the `test` goal and use `-DskipTests`.

Comment: When that is done, is there a way to continue from this point? Without compiling again? Just running the tests next?

Comment: If you later execute e.g., `mvn test`, Maven will execute all of its lifecycle phases again, but as long as you haven't run `clean`, then your build artifacts will still be present and should be up-to-date, making the process much faster. Try it for yourself by running `mvn test-compile; mvn test` vs `mvn test-compile; mvn clean test`

Answer (score 57):

To just compile the tests and code, without running them, just do:

```
mvn test-compile
```

Comment: I think test-compile includes compile

Answer (score 39):

When executing a goal that will include the testing phase (such as package), you can do two things:

- Use the command `mvn -DskipTests=true package`. This will compile all
  tests but not run them.
- Or `mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true package`. This will not compile or run the test branch.

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, you can use `maven.test.skip.exec` option.

```
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip.exec=true
```

Maven will compile the tests without running them.
I use this option in all my projects regularly.

Comment: I was looking into having two pipeline steps: 1. build 2. test
Using this option in step 1 then `mvn surefire:test` in step 2 seems to minimize duplication of things being run.

Answer (score 2):

In case you really want to *only compile the tests* (skip all other phases like `compile`), this will do

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile
```

See the [plugin bindings of the default lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging).

Answer (score 0):

If you settings.xml file you can also use

```
<maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
```

Comment: You should never do that. If you need it, set it on the command line, but never permanently.

Comment: Never said you should or shouldn't do it.  Just providing knowledge of the option.

Comment: This causes maven not to compile the tests, either.

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: why not? this is NOT permanent, that would be to set it in the pom.xml.