# How can I skip tests in maven install goal, while running them in maven test goal?

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project with both integration and unit tests in the same folder (src/test/java). Integration tests are marked with `@Category(IntegrationTest.class)`. I want to end up with the following setup:

1. If I run `mvn install`, I want all tests to compile, but I do not want to execute any.
2. If I run `mvn test`, I want all tests to compile, but execute only unit tests.
3. If I run `mvn integration-test`, I want to compile and execute all tests.

**The important point is, I want this configured in the `pom.xml` without any extra commandline arguments.**

Currently I came up with the following setup in my parent pom.xml, where the only problem is #1, where all tests are executed:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${project.java.version}</source>
                    <target>${project.java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.14.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.class</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludedGroups>cz.cuni.xrg.intlib.commons.IntegrationTest</excludedGroups>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.14.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <groups>cz.cuni.xrg.intlib.commons.IntegrationTest</groups>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.class</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

All child modules have the following plugin configuration in their pom.xml, which I believe should inherit from the parent pom:

```
<build> 
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried using `<skipTests>true</skipTests>`, but it disables test execution for all goals, which is not what I want (violates #2 and #3). It is also quite weird, that `mvn test` honors the `skipTests=true` option...why would I want to run it in the first place??

After hours of googling and trying different combinations, I am hesitant whether it is even possible to not run tests in `mvn install`, while at the same time run them in `mvn test`. I hope someone proves this wrong. ;)

I am also willing to accept a solution, where `mvn install` would execute only unit tests, but I don't think it makes much difference.

Comment: mvn clean install -DskipITs   . :)

Comment: This is one example where gradle would be a better build tool.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

It sounds like you didn't understand the concept of the [build life-cycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) in Maven. If you run `mvn install` all life-cycle phases (including the `install` phase itself) run before the install phase. This means running the following phases:

1. validate
2. initialize
3. generate-sources
4. process-sources
5. generate-resources
6. process-resources
7. compile
8. process-classes
9. generate-test-sources
10. process-test-sources
11. generate-test-resources
12. process-test-resources
13. test-compile
14. process-test-classes
15. test
16. prepare-package
17. package
18. pre-integration-test
19. integration-test
20. post-integration-test
21. verify
22. install

which means in other words the `test` as well as `integration-test` life-cycle phases are included. So without any supplemental information it's not possible to change the behaviour as you wish it.

It could be achieved by using a profile in Maven:

```
 <project>
  [...]
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>no-unit-tests</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  [...]
</project>
```

So your first requirement:

1. If I run `mvn install`, I want all tests to compile, but I do not want to execute any.

can be achieved by using the following:

```
mvn -Pno-unit-test test
```

2. If I run `mvn test`, I want all tests to compile, but execute only unit tests.

This can simply achieved by using the plain call:

```
mvn test
```

cause the integration tests phase is not run (see the build life cycle).

3. If I run `mvn integration-test`, I want to compile and execute all tests.

This means running the default which includes running the `test` phase which will run the unit tests (maven-surefire-plugin) and furthermore running the integration test which are handled by the maven-failsafe-plugin. But you should be aware that if you like to call the integration tests you should using the following command:

```
mvn verify
```

instead, cause you missed the `post-integration-test` phase in your previous call.

Apart from the above you should follow the naming conventions for unit and integration tests where [unit tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) should be named like the following:

```
<includes>
 <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
 <include>**/*Test.java</include>
 <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

and [integration tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) should be named like the following:

```
<includes>
 <include>**/IT*.java</include>
 <include>**/*IT.java</include>
 <include>**/*ITCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

I hope you have configured the maven-failsafe-plugin like the following which is needed to bound the maven-failsafe-plugin to the correct life-cycle-phases:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

as you correctly did, but you should be aware that the `include` tags work on the source code (*.java) and not on the compiled names (*.class). I wouldn't use the Category annotation, just simply using the naming conventions makes the pom simpler and shorter.

Comment: Thank you for an explanation of build life-cycle. I already use profile for skipping tests, but I hoped it could be achieved without the need to switch profiles. I am accepting your answer, because "not possible" is also an answer. :)

Comment: Parameter "-Dmaven.test.skip=true" skips tests run by surefire plugin.

Answer (score 59):

According to the [Failsafe Plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html)

```
mvn install -DskipITs
```

is what you want.

Comment: Link doesn't work, this does: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html

Answer (score 22):

What OP stated in his question:

> If I run **mvn install**, I want all tests to compile, but I do not want
> to execute any.
> If I run **mvn test**, I want all tests to compile, but execute only unit tests.
> If I run **mvn integration-test**, I want to compile and execute all tests.

is perfectly valid and extremely easy to achieve.
*EDIT: except first condition, which acts againts the maven nature. The best way here would be simply do `mvn install -DskipTests`*

All you need is following snippet in `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and to stick to the **maven naming conventions** for unit and integration tests (as @khmarbaise already stated). So generally name you integration tests with `IT` suffix (for example `MyIntegrationTestIT.java`) and let `maven-failsafe` do its job.
In that way, you do not even need JUnit categories (although sometimes they can be quite useful).

That's it :)

- `mvn test`  executes **only** unit tests
- `mvn integration-test`  executes all tests
- `mvn failsafe:integration-test`  runs **only** integration tests
- `mvn clean verify`  when you want to be sure, that whole project just works

### Some personal advices

Keeping integration tests separately from unit tests lets you easily run within your IDE all tests in some package. Usually additional directory called `test-integration` (or `integrationtest`) is used for this purpose.
This is also easy to achieve with maven:

```
<plugin>
    <!-- adding second test source directory (just for integration tests) -->
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-integration-test-source</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-test-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>src/test-integration/java</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And then move your integration tests to that directory. It should look like:

```
src
   main
   test
   test-integration
```

---

Integration tests usually needs more memory:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Loved this answer!

Comment: Thank you! 3 hours of failures to exclude tests from IT :/

Answer (score 12):

[This post](http://esalagea.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/skip-integration-tests-from-maven-deploy/) explains how to skip integration tests, no matter what plugin you are using for these tests.

Basically, what you do is define a profile and put all your integration-tests related xml code inside that profile. Than you activate it when a property `-DskipIntegrationTests` is missing.

You can do the same for unit tests: write a profile and activate it when `-DskipUnitTests` is missing.

Then, you could do:

```
mvn install -DskipIntegrationTests -DskipUnitTests # (runs install without any tests)
mvn test # (runs unit tests)
mvn post-integration-test # (runs all tests)
```

Answer (score 6):

The maven-failsafe-plugin [docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html) has a section titled "Skipping by Default."

Sadly, the steps that page describes don't work as written.  However, a slight change to those steps will make it work:

In the `properties` section of `pom.xml`, add this:

`<skipITs>true</skipITs>`

Then add the `skipTests` property to the `plugin` section of maven-failsafe-plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>${skipITs}</skipTests>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

So now, an `mvn install` by default will execute unit tests, but not integration tests.

But an `mvn install -DskipITs=false` will execute both unit tests and integration tests.

Footnote: Bad documentation played a big part on why Maven was so disliked for such a long time.

Answer (score 2):

`mvn test-compile` does exactly what you are looking for. You can simply replace `mvn install` with `mvn test-compile` and you are done. No need to customise the pom file or anything. The below linked question is similar around #1:

[Maven - How to compile tests without running them ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768660/maven-how-to-compile-tests-without-running-them)

`mvn test-compile` should be accepted as the best answer as Maven supports exactly what you want to do natively and without any magic. You would end up with this:

```
If I run mvn test-compile, I want all tests to compile, but I do not want to execute any.
If I run mvn test, I want all tests to compile, but execute only unit tests.
If I run mvn integration-test, I want to compile and execute all tests.
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the execution step(s) in the configuration of the failsafe plugin. E.g.

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Now, you specifically need to call mvn failsafe:integration-test to run the integration tests; they will be skipped in other mvn targets.