# How to execute multiple goals in one maven command, but with different arguments for each goal

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to run 2 maven goals in one maven command like:

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform -Darguments='-Dmaven.test.skip=true'
```

but, I would like the first goal to skip tests and the second one not to skip tests.

It has to be in one line command.

Is there a way to do it other than executing them in 2 separate commands?

Comment: Could you post your `POM.xml` file content, maybe a minimal content

Comment: Have you looked at profiles? This question may help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117589/how-can-i-skip-tests-in-maven-install-goal-while-running-them-in-maven-test-goa

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true release:prepare release:perform
```

Within release-plugin the arguments are passed via `-Darguments='....'` to the sub process which is started by `release:perform`. The other arguments are passed to the process which is started by `release:prepare`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. -Dmaven.test.skip=true does not skip any tests from any goals

Answer (score 1):

I have spent hours on this.

My working release command is:

```
-Darguments='-DskipTests=true' -DskipTests release:prepare release:perform
```

The problem actually was in my release plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>${release.arguments}</arguments>
```

The "arguments" parameter of the release plugin was overriding the -Darguments that I pass to the release:prepare (in order to be passed to release:perform by release:prepare).